# Expresion Regular no me funciona en FormBuilder

Tags: angular, regex

Estoy trabajando con formularios reactivos en angular y pruebo mis expresiones regulares para validar precios en dólares en la página regexr y me trabajan bien pero veo que en angular no. Por ejemplo La expresión regular `/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2}?$)?/` en la página de regexr dice que dichos números son válidos:

```
156.56
2.56
1
6
99.99
```

Y así lo tengo en en mi FormBuilder:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.frame = this.fb.group({
       // first: defaultValue, validators
       category_id: [ '', [Validators.required]],
       cost: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.pattern("/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2}?$)?/")]],
       stock: [0, [Validators.required, , Validators.min(1)]],
       tax: [0, [Validators.required,  Validators.min(1)]],
       description: ['', [Validators.required]],
       reference: ['', [ Validators.required]],
    })
  }
```

Sin embargo me sale el mensaje que no es válido aun colocando un formato válido como 99.99, 7.45, etc. Necesito ayuda.

Comment: No debes poner los *slashes* (`/`) al principio y final del *pattern*. `Validators.pattern("^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2}?$)?")`. Puedes ver [el ejemplo de la documentación](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Te sobra un `?` en tu expression `/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/`

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.frame = this.fb.group({
      // first: defaultValue, validators

      cost: [
        0,
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(1),
          Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2})?$/)
        ]
      ],
      
    });
  }
```

Aquí tienes un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xpheh4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)